# Distriqt ANE Popover is flickering and goes opaque on android

Tags: air, ane

While using the native dialog popover from distriqt the panel start to flicker and goes opaque after a touch interaction, is there a solution for that?

I am not using stage 3D just simple flash
Device: Samsung S5
Android version: 4.4.2

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]
[image: Image 3]

Comment: Can you provide some more details about your application, what version of Android, AIR etc and if you're using stage3d / starling or similar?

Comment: I have updated my question with screenshots. Thanks!